# Kivy - text wrapping works wrong

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, kivy, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap text in Kivy (1.8.0) application.
When there's not so much text, everything works fine.
But if there's long text and window is not very big, it just cuts the text.

Here's the example code:

```
vbox = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint_y=None)
text = Label(text="Some very long text")
text.bind(size=text.setter("text_size"))
title = Label(text="Some very long title")
title.bind(size=title.setter("text_size"))
vbox.add_widget(title)
vbox.add_widget(text)
```

On mobile devices it's just unbearable.

Screenshots:

#### Full screen

[image: Full screen]

#### Small window

[image: Small window]

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you clarify, the text is not wrapped at all? The bindings to text_size should give you wrapping when it gets horizontally too long.

Answer (score 1):

text_size has to be of the same size of the window so try `text.bind(text_size=text.setter("size"))`

https://kivy.org/planet/2014/07/wrapping-text-in-kivy’s label/ here is an example, but in kv and not in python

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue myself and reading over the [source](https://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/textinput.html) regarding text inputs there's a few functions that handle word wrapping, namely `_split_smart` and `_refresh_hint_text`, and then reading over the [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.input_filter) ran into a *hint* as to what is happening...

> When changing a TextInput property that requires re-drawing, e.g. modifying the text, the updates occur on the next clock cycle and not instantly...

... now *they* don't seem to say it out right but effectively these widgets get assigned their height and width constraints to some default (`width: 50` in the case of text inputs that I tested), then the text if any is shoved through *`_smart_split`* at some point to wrap lines, and never updated again...

The simple solution if you're not concerned about the parent widget's heights being updated too.

```
class cTextInput(TextInput):
    def on_width(self, instance, value):
        self.text = self.text
```

The more complex and complete solution that also updates heights and other magics.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock

from collections import OrderedDict

kv_string = """
#:set rgb_red [1, 0, 0, 0.25]
#:set rgb_purple [0.98, 0.06, 1.0, 0.5]
#:set rgb_green [0.05, 0.47, 0.35, 0.5]
#:set rgb_cyan [0.43, 0.87, 0.81, 0.5]
#:set rgb_blue [0.14, 0.09, 0.76, 0.5]
#:set rgb_salmon [0.98, 0.47, 0.35, 0.5]
#:set rgb_clear [0, 0, 0, 0]

Main_GridLayout: ## Defined root so Builder.load_string returns something useful

<Main_GridLayout>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2
    spacing: 0
    row_force_default: True
    rows_minimum: {0: action_bar.height, 1: self.height - action_bar.height}
    Custom_ActionBar: ## IDs for scope of this widget seem to allow for auto sizing to available space
        id: action_bar
    ScrollView:
        id: scroller


<Custom_ActionBar@ActionBar>: ## Place holder to show that scrolling is within a target widget.
    ActionView:
        ActionPrevious: ## Hidden without side effects
            with_previous: False
            app_icon: ''
            app_icon_width: 0
            app_icon_height: 0
            title: ''
        ActionGroup: ## Text changes with user selection
            id: foobar_action_group
            mode: 'spinner'
            text: 'Foo'
            ActionButton:
                text: "Foo"
                on_press: foobar_action_group.text = self.text
            ActionButton:
                text: "Bar"
                on_press: foobar_action_group.text = self.text


<Adaptive_GridLayout>: ## Going to have to read the Python methods for all of the fanciness this widget has.
    spacing: 10
    row_force_default: True
    size_hint_y: None
    rows_minimum: self.calc_rows_minimum()
    height: self.calc_min_height()

    default_background_color: rgb_green
    selected_background_color: rgb_cyan
    background_color: 0.05, 0.47, 0.35, 0.5
    # background_color: rgb_green ## TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable -- Line 262 of context_instructions.py
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<Row_GridLayout>: ## Inherits from Adaptive_GridLayout
    rows: 1
    spacing: 0
    default_background_color: rgb_blue
    selected_background_color: rgb_salmon
    background_color: rgb_blue ## But this is okay?

    Row_Label:
        id: label


<Row_Label@Label>: ## Example of kv only widget that does stuff
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]

    selected: False

    default_background_color: rgb_clear
    selected_background_color: rgb_red
    background_color: 0, 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.background_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    on_touch_down:
        caller = args[0]
        touch = args[1]

        touched = caller.collide_point(*touch.pos)

        if touched:\
        caller.selected = caller.background_color == caller.default_background_color;\
        print('{0}.selected -> {1}'.format(caller, caller.selected))

        if touched and caller.selected: caller.background_color = self.selected_background_color
        elif touched and not caller.selected: caller.background_color = caller.default_background_color


<Adaptive_TextInput>:
    synopsis_line_limit: 2
    use_bubble: True
    multiline: True
    # readonly: True
    allow_copy: True
    # text: ('Foobarred' * 10) * 40
    text: ''
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

"""


class Adaptive_TextInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, synopsis_line_limit = None, **kwargs):
        self.old_width = self.width
        self.old_height = self.height
        self.synopsis_line_limit = synopsis_line_limit
        self.synopsis_text = ''
        self.full_text = ''

        self.my_hero = super(Adaptive_TextInput, self)
        self.my_hero.__init__(**kwargs)

    def refresh_overflow_values(self, text):
        """ Uses '_split_smart' and '_get_text_width' methods from TextInput to generate synopsis text. """
        self.full_text = text

        lines, lines_flags = self._split_smart(text)
        if self.synopsis_line_limit is None:
            synopsis_line_limit = len(lines)
        else:
            synopsis_line_limit = self.synopsis_line_limit

        if len(lines) > synopsis_line_limit:
            synopsis_lines = lines[:synopsis_line_limit]
            synopsis_line = ''.join(synopsis_lines)
            available_width = self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2]
            text_width = self._get_text_width(synopsis_line, self.tab_width, self._label_cached)
            if (text_width + 3) > available_width:
                self.synopsis_text = '{0}...'.format(synopsis_line[:-3])
            else:
                self.synopsis_text = synopsis_line
        else:
            self.synopsis_text = text

    def refresh_text_value(self):
        """ Sets 'self.text' to either 'self.full_text' or 'self.synopsis_text' based off 'self.focused' value. """
        if self.focused is True:
            self.text = self.full_text
        else:
            self.text = self.synopsis_text
        self._trigger_update_graphics() ## Does not seem to be needed but tis what refreshing of 'hint_text' method does.

    def propagate_height_updates(self):
        """ Update grid layouts to height changes. """
        containing_grids = [g for g in self.walk_reverse() if hasattr(g, 'refresh_grids_y_dimension')]
        for grid in containing_grids:
            grid.refresh_grids_y_dimension()

    def on_focused(self, instance, value):
        """ Sets 'self.focused' value and triggers updates to methods that are interested in such values. """
        self.focused = value
        self.refresh_text_value()
        self.propagate_height_updates()

    def on_size(self, instance, value):
        """ This is the magic that fires updates for line wrapping when widget obtains a new width size as well as
            updating grid layouts and their progenitors on new heights.
        """
        self.my_hero.on_size(instance, value)
        if self.old_width is not self.width: ## Only bother if width has changed
            self.old_width = self.width
            self.refresh_overflow_values(text = self.full_text)
            self.refresh_text_value()
        if self.old_height is not self.height:
            self.old_height = self.height
            self.propagate_height_updates()

    def on_text(self, instance, text):
        """ Updates text values via 'self.refresh_overflow_values(text = value)' only if focused. """
        if self.focused is True:
            self.refresh_overflow_values(text = text)

    def on_parent(self, instance, value):
        """ Wait for parenting to set customized text values because 'self.text' maybe set after initialization. """
        self.refresh_overflow_values(text = self.text)
        self.refresh_text_value()


class Adaptive_GridLayout(GridLayout):
    """ Adaptive height and row heights for grid layouts. """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.my_hero = super(Adaptive_GridLayout, self)
        self.my_hero.__init__(**kwargs)

    def yield_tallest_of_each_row(self):
        """ Yields tallest child of each row within gridlayout. """
        current_tallest = None
        for i, c in enumerate(list(reversed(self.children))):
            if current_tallest is None:
                current_tallest = c

            if c.height > current_tallest.height:
                current_tallest = c

            if self.cols is None or self.cols is 0: ## Should work around grids without value for 'cols'
                yield current_tallest
                current_tallest = None
            elif ((i + 1) % self.cols == 0) is True: ## Reached last item of current row.
                yield current_tallest
                current_tallest = None

    def calc_child_padding_y(self, child):
        """ Returns total padding for a given child. """
        try: ## Likely faster than asking permission with an if statement as most widgets seem to have padding
            child_padding = child.padding
        except AttributeError as e:
            child_padding = [0]

        len_child_padding = len(child_padding)
        if len_child_padding is 1:
            padding = child_padding[0] * 2
        elif len_child_padding is 2:
            padding = child_padding[1] * 2
        elif len_child_padding > 2:
            padding = child_padding[1] + child_padding[3]
        else:
            padding = 0

        return padding

    def calc_min_height(self):
        """ Returns total height required to display tallest children of each row plus spacing between widgets. """
        min_height = 0
        for c in self.yield_tallest_of_each_row():
            c_height = c.height + self.calc_child_padding_y(child = c)
            min_height += c_height + self.spacing[1]
        return min_height

    def calc_rows_minimum(self):
        """ Returns ordered dictionary of how high each row should be to accommodate tallest children of each row. """
        rows_minimum = OrderedDict()
        for i, c in enumerate(self.yield_tallest_of_each_row()):
            c_height = c.height + self.calc_child_padding_y(child = c)
            rows_minimum.update({i: c_height})
        return rows_minimum

    def refresh_height(self):
        """ Resets 'self.height' using value returned by 'calc_min_height' method. """
        self.height = self.calc_min_height()

    def refresh_rows_minimum(self):
        """ Resets 'self.rows_minimum' using value returned by 'calc_rows_minimum' method. """
        self.rows_minimum = self.calc_rows_minimum()

    def refresh_grids_y_dimension(self):
        """ Updates 'height' and 'rows_minimum' first for spawn, then for self, and finally for any progenitors. """
        grid_spawn = [x for x in self.walk(restrict = True) if hasattr(x, 'refresh_grids_y_dimension') and x is not self]
        for spawn in grid_spawn:
            spawn.refresh_rows_minimum()
            spawn.refresh_height()

        self.refresh_rows_minimum()
        self.refresh_height()

        grid_progenitors = [x for x in self.walk_reverse() if hasattr(x, 'refresh_grids_y_dimension') and x is not self]
        for progenitor in grid_progenitors:
            progenitor.refresh_rows_minimum()
            progenitor.refresh_height()

    def on_parent(self, instance, value):
        """ Some adjustments maybe needed to get top row behaving on all platforms. """
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda _ : self.refresh_grids_y_dimension(), 0.461251)

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        """ Place to throw debugging lines for test interactions as this should be removed before release. """
        touched = self.collide_point(*touch.pos)
        spawn_touched = [x.collide_point(*touch.pos) for x in self.walk(restrict = True) if x is not self]
        if touched is True and True not in spawn_touched: ## Example of how to fire on lonely touches...
            if self.background_color == self.default_background_color:
                self.background_color = self.selected_background_color
            else:
                self.background_color = self.default_background_color

            print('{0}.height -> {1}'.format(self, self.height))
            for c in self.children:
                print('\t{0}.height -> {1}'.format(c, c.height))

        else: ## ... and return to defaults if others where touched.
            self.background_color = self.default_background_color

        ## Supering allows spawn to also register touch events
        self.my_hero.on_touch_down(touch)


class Row_GridLayout(Adaptive_GridLayout):
    """ Magic is inherited from Adaptive_GridLayout, mostly... """
    def on_parent(self, instance, value):
        """ Overwriting inherited on_parent method to avoid over calling Clock. """
        pass


class Main_GridLayout(GridLayout):
    """ Check 'kv_string' for layout widgets. """
    pass


class SomeApp(App):
    """ SomeApp flaunts it because it has gots it. """
    def build(self):
        root_layout = Builder.load_string(kv_string)

        container = Adaptive_GridLayout(cols = 1)
        for x in range(0, 5):
            # row = Row_GridLayout(rows = 1) ## IndexError: list index out of range -- Line 324 of gridlayout.py
            row = Row_GridLayout(cols = 2)
            row.ids.label.text = 'Row #{0}'.format(x)

            ## Growing amount of junk text quickly on each iteration for swifter demonstration
            text = 'Foobarred' * ((x + 1) * (x + 2))
            textinput = Adaptive_TextInput()
            textinput.text = text

            row.add_widget(textinput)
            container.add_widget(row)

        root_layout.ids.scroller.add_widget(container)

        return root_layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SomeApp().run()
```