# How do you compacted a GridLayout vertical space in Kivy?

Tags: python, layout, kivy

Have a look at the screenshot below:

[image: Kivy GridLayout screenshot]

I kinda new in this Kivy layout scheme, previously I work a lot in PyQt. In PyQt, that blank vertical space can easily get rid of by using Spacer. But how do you do this in Kivy? Below is part of the KV file that constitute this layout.

```
GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '48dp'
            row_force_default: True
            spacing: 10, 10
            padding: 10, 10

            Label:
                size_hint: None, None
                text: 'Input'
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text_size: self.size
                width: 50
            TextInput:
                id: txt_url
                size_hint: 1, None
                text: ''

        TabbedPanel:
            id: tp
            do_default_tab: False

            TabbedPanelItem:
                id: tab_fl
                text: ''
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: ''
                FloatLayout
                    id: box
            TabbedPanelItem:
                text: ''
                FloatLayout
                    id: box
```

I Would love to know what is the best practice of using Kivy layout mechanism. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can take advantage of the `GridLayout`'s `minimum_height` property to size it appropriately.

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        row_default_height: '48dp'
        row_force_default: True
        spacing: 10, 10
        padding: 10, 10

        # add these two lines
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height

        ...
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, I have tried this for sure. But it cause the below tabbed panel to have a short height. Making it again ugly. I redesigned the app to have all the controls lay inside that below tabbed panel

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using one column width in your root `GridLayout`, it be possible to resize the rows based off children height using the following trick for setting `rows_minimum`.

```
GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    row_force_default: True
    ## Call it what ya like, just interested in setting 'self.rows_minimum'
    foo: [self.rows_minimum.update({i: x.height}) for i, x in enumerate(reversed(list(self.children)))]
    ## ... rest of layout ...
```

The internal `GridLayout` and `TabbedPanel` are the rows/children of your root `GridLayout`, so setting heights for the internal elements *should* allow for the `foo` generator redirection to *pull-up* the excess space.

Now for readers that may have more than one column there be a more extensive example, that shows one way of handling auto-sizing of grid layouts and a bunch of other goodies, over at another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50539538/2632107) regarding text input word wrapping.